# How can I use do.call() to read specific rows?

Tags: r, data.table, do.call

I'm using the do.call() command to read a list of csv-files to have all data points in one csv file. I have been using the following:

```
files = list.files(path = "G:/SafeGraph201708MidWest",
                     pattern = "*.csv",
                     recursive = TRUE,
                     full.names = TRUE)

library(data.table)
  DT = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, fread))
```

Instead of reading all the rows in each file, I want to read specific rows. Especially the ones that are within this range:

```
Data <- filter(DT, longitude >= -86.97 & longitude <= -86.78, 
                 latitude >= 40.35 & latitude <= 40.49)
```

Is there a way that I can do that using do.call()? Looking forward for a soon reply. Thank you!

Comment: Not an answer but see `rbindlist {data.table}`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Can you privide a sample of the csv-file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several strategies on how to tackle this. You can import all the data into a list using `lapply` and then from each list element filter out based on your filter. You would use `data.table::rbindlist` to make the final data.table. Another one would be to do this in one step, e.g. (not tested, obviously)

```
library(data.table)

files = list.files(path = "G:/SafeGraph201708MidWest",
                   pattern = "*.csv",
                   recursive = TRUE,
                   full.names = TRUE)

xy <- lapply(files, FUN = function(x) {
  out <- fread(x)
  out <- filter(out, longitude >= -86.97 & longitude <= -86.78, 
                latitude >= 40.35 & latitude <= 40.49)
  out
})

xy <- rbindlist(xy)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still require *reading all the rows in each file* which OP does not want?

Comment: That would require some extra work. Unless the data wouldn't fit into RAM, I would not bother devising such a solution.

Comment: Btw - consider using the bracketed filter method of `data.table` instead of what appears to be `dplyr`.

Comment: @Parfait I'll leave that to the OP to optimize their code. This is just a proof of concept, which was the original question, I believe.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This code worked to perfection. The problem that I was having is that I was storing the read files so then I filter the data that I want and since the data is very large it was crashing my computer. Then, I created a loop to read each file, filter the data that I want on each file and then stored the final data in a data frame. But that was messing with one of my character columns. I've tried this function that you suggested and it worked exactly how I wanted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Windows PC and have at least Microsoft Office 2007+ installed, consider directly querying the CSV with the JET/ACE SQL Engine (.dll files) which is the very engine of MS Access.

Below includes two connection strings using Access or Excel. Either version works and the files do need to exist but are never used except for connecting to ACE. Once connected, CSV files are then queried from same or different path.

```
library(odbc)

# VERIFY AVAILABLE DSNs AND DRIVERS
odbcListDataSources()

# DSN VERSIONS
conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), DSN ="MS Access Database;DBQ=C:\\Path\\To\\Access.accdb;");
conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), DSN ="Excel Files;DBQ=C:\\Path\\To\\Excel.xlsx;");

# DRIVER VERSIONS
conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                  .connection_string = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Path\\To\\Access.accdb;");    
conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                  .connection_string ="Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=C:\\Path\\To\\Excel.xlsx;");

# CSV QUERY
df <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT t.* 
                        FROM [text;database=C:\\Path\\To\\CSV_Folder].Name_of_File.csv AS t 
                        WHERE t.longitude BETWEEN -86.97 AND -86.78
                          AND t.latitude BETWEEN 40.35 AND 40.49;")    
head(df)

dbDisconnect(conn)
```

And in a loop:

```
files = list.files(path = "G:/SafeGraph201708MidWest",
                   pattern = "*.csv",
                   recursive = TRUE,
                   full.names = TRUE)    

df_list <- lapply(files, function(f)    
    df <- dbGetQuery(conn, 
                     paste0("SELECT t.* ",
                            " FROM [text;database=G:\\SafeGraph201708MidWest].", f, " AS t ",
                            " WHERE t.longitude BETWEEN -86.97 AND -86.78", 
                            "   AND t.latitude BETWEEN 40.35 AND 40.49;")
                    )    
)

final_dt <- rbindlist(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ability from `data.table::fread()` to execute a command and 'read' he results.

I Assume you are using windows, so you have got accessto the `findstr`-function in your command prompt.

So, if you can build a regex that 'hits' on the lines you want to extract, you can filter wanted lines before reading the entire file into R. This is (potentially) a huuuge memory-saver on larger files, and may speed up your workflow considerably.

**sample data**

lat's say coords.csv looks line this:

```
id,latitude,longitude
1,10,11
2,11,12
3,12,13
4,13,14
5,14,15
```

In this example, you want to extract lines with latitudes bewteen 12 and 14 AND longitudes beteeen 11 and 13

**code**

```
#build a list of files (I created only one)
#make sure you use the full path (not relative)
x <- list.files( path = "C:/folder", pattern = "coord.csv", full.names = TRUE )

#build reges that only hits on rows with:
#  latitude 12-14
#  longitude 11-13
pattern = "^[0-9],1[2-4],1[1-3]$"

#read the file(s), extract the lines with match the regex-pattern 
#and bind the resuklt to a data.table
rbindlist( lapply( x, function(x) { 
  fread( cmd = paste0( "findstr /R ", pattern, " ", x ), header = FALSE ) 
} ) )
```

**output**

```
    V1 V2 V3
 1:  3 12 13
```

Comment: The real challenge here is: Can you build a regex to extract the rows you need (if your data is in a tidy csv- format, this wil probabaly not be toohard) ? Without a sample of your csv-files/data, I cannot say for sure.